# How can I create a Rails form that POSTs to this custom route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this route...

```
match '/set_current_location/:contract_id' => 'contracts#set_current_location',
  :as => :set_current_location
```

I've written the `ContractsController#set_current_location` action and tests and that's all working as expected.

I'm having trouble with the view code.

I understand that this isn't The Rails Way, but because of the underlying DB structure (which I didn't create and am not allowed to change), it would be best in this one special case to not base the form on a model at all.

So my question is, how can I create a non-model form that posts to that route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<%= form_tag(set_current_location_path(contract_id), method: :post) do %>
...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be working: form_tag(set_current_location_path(contract.id)).

Comment: Great! and yes the param should be there.